# How to read search and print output in lang C

Tags: c

i need help with this little project i made the write part but i cant understand the read part when using scanf of string value and search for it  and printf (display) the output like this when i enter the name

```
Name: Ahsan Iqbal 
Phone No.: bla bla bla
Address: bla bla bla
RESULT:
BEE: 90.00
CF&P: 90.00
Physics: 90.00
P.st: 90.00
C&AG: 90.00
Total Percentage: 90.00 ;
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    int x=1;
    FILE *f = fopen("Data.txt", "a+");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
    FILE *f = fopen("Data.txt", "w");
    }
    do
    {
    printf("Please Select Options\n1.New Entry \n2.Search Entry \n3.Exit \nOption:");
    scanf(" %d",&x);
    if(x == 1)                         //new entry
    {
        float z[5];
        char y,name[100],phone[20],address[256];
        printf("Please Enter Name\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",&name);
        printf("Please Enter Phone Number\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",&phone);
        printf("Please Enter The Address\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",&address);
        printf("Do you want to save result (y/n)\n");
        scanf(" %c",&y);
        if (y == 'y' || y == 'Y')
        {
            printf("Please Enter BEE Marks\n");
            scanf(" %f",&z[0]);
            printf("Please Enter CF&P Marks\n");
            scanf(" %f",&z[1]);
            printf("Please Enter Physics Marks\n");
            scanf(" %f",&z[2]);
            printf("Please Enter P.st Marks\n");
            scanf(" %f",&z[3]);
            printf("Please Enter C&AG Marks\n");
            scanf(" %f",&z[4]);
            z[5] = ((z[0] +z[1] +z[2] +z[3] +z[4])/500)*100;
        }
        fprintf(f, "Name: %s \n",name );
        fprintf(f, "Phone No.: %s\n",phone );
        fprintf(f, "Address: %s\n",address );
        if (y == 'y' || y == 'Y')
        {
            fprintf(f, "RESULT:\n");
            fprintf(f, "BEE: %3.2f\n",z[0] );
            fprintf(f, "CF&P: %3.2f\n",z[1] );
            fprintf(f, "Physics: %3.2f\n",z[2] );
            fprintf(f, "P.st: %3.2f\n",z[3] );
            fprintf(f, "C&AG: %3.2f\n",z[4] );
            fprintf(f, "Total Percentage: %3.2f ;\n",z[5] );
        }
    }
    else if (x == 2)                           //Search
     {
        char name[100],temp[256];
        printf("Please Enter First Name To Search\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",&name);                 //need help after this
        while(!feof(f)) {
        fgets(name, 100, f);
        printf(" %s", name);
        }
     }
    printf("\n\n");
    }while(x <= 2);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]",&name);` because `name` is an array of chars, you do not take the "address of (`&`)", so it becomes: `scanf(" %[^\n]",name);`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Using a pointer to the array is *semantically* wrong, but as it points to the same location as the first element in the array it works out in the end.

Comment: `z[5] = ` but there isn't a `z[5]`. Breaking the array bounds is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) That loop would be better as `while(fgets(name, sizeof name, f) != NULL) { printf(" %s", name); }` and remember too that `fgets` retains any newline from the input.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for pointing out i forgot to increase that to [6] but the main problem is at search

Comment: First you need to find a line that starts with `"Name: "` such as with `if(strstr(name, "Name: ") == name)` and then you can examine the string at `(name+6)` for the target name, making sure the next character is a space, so that you don't mistake the name "Roberta" for "Robert", for example.

Comment: Still no luck can anyone give help me by give search code with respect to source code